# R deleting duplicates when duplicates slightly differ by 1 or 2 letters

Tags: regex, r, twitter, duplicates, nlp

I am collecting tweets with the twitteR package and get many duplicates. This code works fine:

```
tweets <- searchTwitter(keyword, n=500, lang="en", since=NULL, until=NULL,  retryOnRateLimit=100)
mydata <- sapply(tweets, function(x) x$getText())
mydata <- unique(mydata, incomparables = F, nmax = NA)
```

The problem is that it actually doesn't delete any duplicates because it doesn't recognises them as such. The duplicate tweets typically contain shortened URLS that differ by 1 or 2 digits. So I tried to clean the tweets of URLS with this code:

```
tweets <- searchTwitter(keyword, n=500, lang="en", since=NULL, until=NULL, 
retryOnRateLimit=100)
mydata <- sapply(tweets, function(x) x$getText())
mydata <- data.frame(tweetsText, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)  
names(mydata) <- c('words')
removeURL <- function(x) gsub("http[[:alnum:]]*", "", x)
mydata$words <- removeURL(mydata$words)
removeURL <- function(x) gsub("https[[:alnum:]]*", "", x)
mydata$words <- removeURL(mydata$words) 
mydata$words <- unique(mydata$words, incomparables = F, nmax = NA)
```

Now I get the error message:
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "words", value = c("Tripping around @DisneySprings.....) : replacement has 295 rows, data has 300

Advice? Thanks!

Comment: Check out the `stringdist` package, you can do `amatch` which uses levenshtein distance

Comment: @Shape thanks will check that out.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is easily reproducible:

```
mydata <- data.frame(list(w = c(0, 1, 0, 1)))
mydata$words <- c(0, 1, 1)
# Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "words", value = c(0, 1, 1)) : 
# replacement has 3 rows, data has 4
```

This just means that you need to assign a vector of the same length as the length of the data frame.

To filter out duplicate values you need to change the last line of your code to:

```
res <- mydata[!duplicated(mydata$words), ]
```

Comment: thanks for the idea. But I have no idea how to do that. I am working with natural data (tweets) they come in different lengths. Cutting of from letters to create an arbitrary defined length can change the meaning of the text (tweet) which is important for me. The content per row(tweet) is my level of analysis.